# Suzuku Katana does not start after an accident

Tags: electrical, motorcycle, starting, suzuki, katana

I have a Suzuki Katana GSX600F.

After an accident I was in, I rode the bike home and all was fine except a little cosmetic damage. In rainstorm it tipped over and after picking it up and trying to fire it up, it started smoking slightly, so I turned it off and removed the gas tank, and noticed a wire was split and burnt. I replaced the wire, got it all put back together, and now the lights all come on and stuff, but does nothing when I push the start button.

I’ve checked all the fuses and they are fine. I’m not sure where to go from here.

Comment: More details, please. What year is the bike? What wire was fried? What would have caused that damage?

Answer (score 6):

**Two Possibilities**

Off the top of my head I would look at the following:

- **The clutch start switch** - a broken wire or switch will prevent you from starting the bike.  It disables the starter relay by grounding it out unless you pull in the clutch.  It's located on the handlebar and is integrated into the clutch lever landing.
- **Side Stand Switch** - See if the side stand switch hits properly on your kick stand.  If it does not get depressed when the side stand is up then your starter relay is going to ground and you will not be able to start it.
- **Tip Over Sensor** - You have a tip over sensor in the rear of the motorcycle.  I believe it's under the passenger or the riders seats.  It will have an arrow that needs to point up when it is properly mounted.  Validate that this device has not come loose.

**Other Possibilities**

- **Dead battery**
- **Blown fuse** - If it is a blown fuse on your starter relay circuit the fuse is in the back of the bike under the seats inside your starter relay.  It's a 20 or 30 amp fuse and is NOT ON YOUR FUSE BLOCK with all the other fuses.

Your starter relay is required by regulation to have a plastic removable cover.  It looks like this.

By default, it will come with a spare fuse in it.  You will see it once you remove the snap on plastic cover.  If it's been used you will need to procure a new one at your local auto parts store.

[image]

Comment: There might be an inline safety diode in the harness as well.  Some bikes have these.  Need the wiring schematic for it to be sure.  There is also a tipover switch that may not have completely reset as well.

Answer (score 5):

Start from the beginning. Check your battery. Then check your fried cables. Try to fix as much as possible. Make sure nothing is short-circuited.

If all looks good, pull out the electric wiring diagram and identify all the items which prevents it from starting. Measure all these points and make sure there is no short/open circuits. The obvious would be: side stand and emergency break switch.

The previous would be first items you can check. If all of this fails, you will have to dig deeper. Anyway, this would get you started...

Comment: I have already started tearing all of the wiring tube off and found a couple fried wires, so im going to fix all of these wires and trickle charge my battery and just start from the beginning! Thanks and if all fails and I have any more questions, I will get back to you!!