# 2003 Suzuki Katana GSX600F - No Start Issue

Tags: electrical, motorcycle, starter, suzuki, katana

So I recently purchased this motorcycle from a third party. 2 days ago it would start up fine and you could ride it. The guy I brought it from said the battery was acting cranky so you should change it.

That same day I had the bike on the kickstand and it dropped on its left side and I also believe I had the switch on (the red button on the right side of the bike) but ignition off. When I picked the bike up I didn't think about starting it I just put it away. The next day I changed the battery and my bike would not start. It would make a few noises, nothing from the exhaust pipes though. After a couple times I would get no noise when I tried starting the bike and eventually the lights dimmed on the bike and the back lights wouldn't be lit.

I also found a plug to something on the right side of the bike in between  the oil tank and the battery that was not connected. I couldn't find no place that the plug could possibly go to. Even with the plug as it is the bike would make the noise but eventually I would get nothing. Any thoughts?

[image: left side of bike is picture 1]

[image: right side of bike is picture 2]

[image]

[[image]][

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Post some pictures it might help.

Comment: If you register yourself as a user and go through the login process, we can interact much better and possibly chat if we need to in order to help you get sorted.   Go here and do that.  Once your done, we can link this question up to you.         https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fmechanics.stackexchange.com%2f

Comment: You say you changed the battery the next day...  Did the new battery have enough time to properly charge?  Also, check the basics - bike is in neutral and the kill switch is on.

Comment: Unregistered user.  Doubt we'll get any comms.

Comment: I just put the new batter in and right after tried to start it. And all that happened was my lights being back to normal. But after a few attempts of starting it with the bike in neutral and kill switch on the lights eventually dimmed... And I'll try to post a picture of the plugs I found

Comment: @racefever how do you post a picture ?

Comment: @DucatiKiller Found two short plugs on both sides of the bike no plugged in. I'm just trying to find out how to post a picture up here , I'm clueless on that

Comment: below your question there is an edit button > Click it > above the editable text there will be a square icon that might resemble a mountain with a dot in the upper right hand corner of the square > click that > you can then upload your picture, share a link, etc...drag your pic onto it.  It should show up in your editable text so you can place it where you want.

Comment: I'm not getting no little box to post a picture on this app or on the site @DucatiKiller

Comment: Are you using the mobil app or a full desktop?

Comment: Mobil app @DucatiKiller

Comment: android or iphone.  Sorry, should have asked earlier

Comment: either way, there is a picture of a camera on the app so you can upload an image

Comment: @DucatiKiller 1st picture is left side & 2nd picture is right

Comment: right on.   the last picture is for a horn the bike comes with one of them.

Comment: The first picture, I'm not sure what you are trying to show.  maybe put an arrow on it or do a closeup of exactly what item in the photo you are concerned with but I'm pretty sure I know what's wrong.

Comment: In that last picture the piece is covered with electrical tape, I'm assuming the perso who had it last put it there. And what do you think it is ? ? @DucatiKiller

Comment: I put up an answer.  Try to screw with the clutch switch.  I'm almost positive that's your issue since you dropped the bike on the left side.  I've done the same thing with GSXR 600's and 1000's and it's always the switch.  good luck.  I'll be online in the afternoon tomorrow.  I'm Pacific Time US.  Cheers.

Comment: I added an edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38126/discussion-between-ducatikiller-and-torey).

Comment: do you have to reset the float level if you replace a float in the carburetor....

Answer (score 10):

**I believe your clutch safety switch has been damaged**

You have a switch underneath your clutch lever.

It forces you to pull the clutch in to start the bike.

There is a small phillips head #2 screw that holds in place.  It can be adjusted and slid back and forth to engage properly with the clutch lever.  You can see where the switch hits the lever if you look at the underside of the clutch lever.  As well, the wire to the switch may have fallen off.  It plugs back in easily.

Here is another post where this is listed as a possible issue after an owner dropped their Katana.

- **[Suzuku Katana does not start after an accident](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/6486/suzuku-katana-does-not-start-after-an-accident/24640#24640)**

Here is the part on parts explosion of the [clutch switch](http://www.2wheelpros.com/oem-parts/2000-suzuki-katana-gsx750f-handle-switch-assembly.html?partnum=37560-38A00).  It's #8.  The image is for a 2000 750 but it's the same as yours.

**EDIT:**

- You also have a side stand switch that your kickstand hits when it is up.  Make sure that is in place and the kickstand can hit it properly. It's a grounding switch and your bike can't run unless the switch is ***depressed***
- You have a tip over sensor attached to your battery box.  That's the plastic shell your batter rests in. The tip over sensor has a black rubber encasement that wraps around 4 sides of it. The tip over sensor is black. It has an arrow stamped on it, not the rubber but the plastic. You want that arrow pointed up to the sky. If it's not pointed in that direction, the bike won't start.

Good luck, you have to know it's something simple.  The bike fell over, now it doesn't start. Chances are the two events are related. I'm just saying, don't overthink it, it's probably something not complicated. Good luck troubleshooting. It's the stuff of life.

Comment: Thanks man I appreciate it, I'll try it all tomorrow and let you know how it goes .

Comment: Put in an edit in your post for the three wire colors on that wrapped thing.  Looked like one was pink and another black but I need to know how many wires and the colors of each.  example would be white w/ a brown stripe, etc...anyway,  good luck and your welcome.  You gotta ride your new bike.

Comment: Alright yeah I'll get that for you tomorrow @DucatiKiller

Answer (score 2):

You should place the old battery back in and check if it starts there.. If it does, then there could possible be something faulty about the battery you replaced it with (Try getting a brand new battery instead).

After the bike fell to the side, was there any damage? Check if anything was broken (e.g. power cables etc.). That could be one thing to do, just give the bike a general check over making sure everything is connected correctly.

As for the plug, it is likely its a testing plug used when doing maintenance on the bike, and should sit in a little slot made it for it.

(Note: This is just general knowledge of a everyday person, I do not own said bike, this is just what I would do if I was in the same situation as yourself)

Comment: There is no test plug on any Suzuki model that comes out the side.  They are all very short plugs under the passenger seat.

Comment: Yeah I found a short plug on the right side not connected covered with electrical tape behind the fairing and another on the left side. I no longer have the old battery, traded it for a new one. Today I tried again to start it and I would sometimes get a tick then eventually all the lights dimmed again after a few times of trying to start the bike. I checked underneath the clutch and it's connected it looks fine